# What are the advantage of writing angular app using standalone components

Tags: angular-components, ng-modules, angular-standalone-components

I have seen many docs regarding standalone components creation and its usage.
But i havent found any doc stating the advantages of standalone components implementation against ngmodules approach.

We can get rid of too many module s creation and checking over for declaring them and so on.

Are there any other major advantages with build time, tree shaking, components loading?